# how can parse complete JSON data dynamically without knowing JSONObject and JSONArray name and structure?

Tags: android, json

I want to get the JSON data without knowing any name and structure. Actually, we have multiple table name as (array name) and column name as(key, value) and I want to get it dynamically and store parsed data(values) on parsed columns(keys) into SQLite database according to parsed table name(array name).

This JSON data is demo data and table name can be more than 20  but data is coming like this, so please help me to solve this problem.

```
{
  "MSG": "OK",
  "data": [
    {
      "strPrimaryKey": "iDeviceAppId",
      "Device_App": [
        {
          "strAppName": "NI Data Dashbard",
          "isDeleted": "0",
          "strVersion": "2.3.0",
          "dtCreateDate": "2018-04-09",
          "iDeviceAppId": "0",
          "dtUpdateDate": "2018-04-11",
          "iOnHomeScreen": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "strPrimaryKey": "iDeviceAppId",
      "Table_App": [
        {
          "strAppName": "NI Data Dashbard",
          "isDeleted": "0",
          "strVersion": "1.8.0",
          "dtCreateDate": "2018-04-09",
          "iDeviceAppId": "0",
          "dtUpdateDate": "2018-04-11",
          "iOnHomeScreen": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "strPrimaryKey": "iDeviceAppId",
      "Device_App": [
        {
          "strAppName": "NI Data Dashbard",
          "isDeleted": "0",
          "strVersion": "2.3.0",
          "dtCreateDate": "2018-04-09",
          "iDeviceAppId": "0",
          "dtUpdateDate": "2018-04-11",
          "iOnHomeScreen": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use an iterator to iterate through the object to extract and map key-value pairs

Comment: thank you for helping me..but i need more clear code which help me to resolve my problem..because i do not know what data is coming ..so I have to parsed it and use it for insert values into table.

Comment: If that is your real data and array names are only changing and you know all the array name then you can check it with if condition only.
Or you can use an iterator to get the JsonArray key.

Comment: thanks , but i do not know the coming structure not object name and not array name..

Comment: JSONArray updateData = new JSONArray(allCallResponses[6]); for (int i = 0; i < updateData.length(); i++) { JSONObject object_one = updateData.getJSONObject(i); Iterator<String> keys = object_one.keys(); while (keys.hasNext()) { Keys = (String) keys.next(); Values = object_one.getString(Keys); } }

Comment: There must be some structure. It might be of 5 different variant but there must be one.

Comment: Don't put your question on comment section rather edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: this code i am using to solve my problem but it is only giving the single key and value at a time

Comment: That's because your array has one Json Object only.

Answer (score 0):

this the solution for it

```
String data = "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //you have an array
```

And to know the key at run-time dynamically use iterator

Comment: thank you for helping me..but i need more clear code which help me to resolve my problem..because i do not know what data is coming ..so I have to parsed it and use it for insert values into table.

Comment: mohit the thing you have to do is just pass your response string in jsontokener and get the keys using iterator in if and if else condition and do your parsing , I cannot do the complete code here , i can only guide you the way to do it

Comment: JSONArray updateData = new JSONArray(allCallResponses[6]);

                            for (int i = 0; i < updateData.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject object_one = updateData.getJSONObject(i);

                                Iterator<String> keys = object_one.keys();
                                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                                    Keys = (String) keys.next();
                                    Values = object_one.getString(Keys);

                                }
                            }

Comment: i am using this code to solve my problem..but it giving me the first array data only..and if i want to next array then i will have to iterate again..but i want to complete data in one iteration  , if it is possible.and thank you once again for helping me